# Move Documents between collections in ArangoDB

Tags: nosql, arangodb, aql, pyarango

Is there a simple way to move documents between collections in ArangoDB?
I tried the cheap approach to just alter the `_id`, but as feared that's not supposed to be done or possible:

```
FOR i IN collection_A
UPDATE { _key: i._key, _id: CONCAT('collection_B/',i._key) } IN collection_A
```

Are there useful ways how I can move my document from `collection_A` to `collection_B` with AQL?

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like

```
FOR i IN collection_A
    LET i_b = UNSET(i, "_id") // Remove the id that is not valid before insert
    INSERT i_b INTO collection_B
    REMOVE i IN collection_A
```

Comment: Gladly upvote as it's working code which helps. Yet I'm rather curious if there's some quicker or more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Just do an insert instead of an update
For I in collection_A
Insert  into collection_B

Comment: It's about efficiency. If there are ways to do it with as little as possible modifications

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-data-modification-queries.html#copying-data-from-one-collection-into-another

```
FOR u IN collection_A
   INSERT u IN collection_B
```